# How can I talk to my daughter's father (whom I was never married with)?

Tags: nikah

I have a daughter, but her father and I were never married.  Myself, my child's father and his new wife are all converted Muslims.

I am now being told that since my daughter's father is married I can no longer have any contact with him — not even concerning my daughter — rather I would need to talk to his wife.  However, she and I do not get along well.

I am told that this is in the "Sunna".  What exactly can I do in this situation?

Comment: did you ask what is the bases for forbidding you from talking to that person?

Comment: if you don't have time to read an answer, why do you bother posting a question? @shor rat is trying to clarify something for you so please respond.

Comment: "what can i do" is off topic. it would been a good question though; **"What does Islam say about talking to my daughters father (concerning my daughter), when we are not married?"**